# Implicit conversion error - why is this code trying to convert a 'World' to an 'int'?

Tags: unity, c#

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class World {
    Tile[,] tiles;
    int width;
    int height;

    public World (int width = 200, int height = 200) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;

        tiles = new Tile[width, height];

        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
                tiles[x, y] = new Tile[this, x, y];
            }
        }
    }

    public Tile GetTileAt(int x, int y) {
        if (x > width || x < 0 || y > height || y < 0) {
            Debug.LogError ("Tile (" + x + ", " + y + ") is out of range");
            return null;
        }
        return tiles [x, y];
    }

}
```

anyone see anything wrong with this code because on line 18 of my code i get this error "cannot implicitly convert type 'World' to 'int' and i don't know what is going wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is it safe to presume this line is the culprit?

```
tiles[x, y] = new Tile[this, x, y];
```

(It never hurts to annotate your code with a comment like `\\ This line generates the following error...` to ensure it's clear for people trying to help)

It looks like you're trying to call a constructor for the `Tile` class, passing `this` world as the first argument. But instead of using **round parentheses ( )** for a function call, you've used the **square brackets [ ]** of an array index or size declaration.

So, this says "Make a new 3-dimensional array of tiles, where the first dimension's length is the integer `this`" ...but `this` isn't an integer, `this` is a `World`!

Thus the compiler throws up its hands and says "fix this - you've asked me to do something nonsensical here" ;)

Comment: yeah thats the line thats throwing me a error, so are you saying that i should change it from [] to ()?

Comment: Yep! `new SomeType[...]` means "I'm creating a new array with the following dimensions" while `new SomeType(...)` means I'm creating a new object/struct with the following constructor arguments"